# Tokenizing english text with the word ".NET" in it using Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have english text with the word ".NET" in it. Using the standard english tokenizer, this gets tokenized to the two tokens "." and "NET".

[image: Output of Stanford CoreNLP tokenization]

Since .NET is a valid word/token, is this a problem in the tokenization model? As a point of comparison, Python NLTK tokenizes this properly:

```
>>> nltk.word_tokenize('The .NET CLR is cool.')
['The', '.NET', 'CLR', 'is', 'cool', '.']
```

Secondly, given that is the current state of tokenization in CoreNLP, what is the best work-around? My initial thought is to use `invertible=true` on the tokenizer options, and then create a `UntokenizeAnnotator` which uses the token annotations to find instances of the two tokens "." and "NET" with the appropriate before/after information, and combine them back together. This seems like a real hack though.

Perhaps I should instead figure out how to re-train the tokenizer model?

**UPDATE**: I worked around this with an `UntokenizeAnnotator` as described above. However, I'm still be interested in more elegant answers to this question.